# Flip a sequential row column number by group and serpentine a matrix in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset where i need to change the order of the row from top to bottom to bottom to top. So I have an example data of where I start and then A finaldf3 where I want to end. I have reps so each rep needs to be grouped then max row needs to become the minium row and so on.

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(Entry = sample.int(48), 
                Row = rep(c(1:4), c(12,12,12,12)), 
                Range = rep(c(1:12),4), 
                Rep = rep(1,48)
                )

set.seed(2)
df2 = data.frame(Entry = sample.int(48), 
                Row = rep(c(5:8), c(12,12,12,12)), 
                Range = rep(c(1:12),4), 
                Rep = rep(2,48)
                )

df3 = rbind(df, df2)

set.seed(1)
finaldf = data.frame(Entry = sample.int(48), 
                     Row = rep(c(4:1), c(12,12,12,12)), 
                     Range = rep(c(1:12),4), 
                     Rep = rep(1,48))
set.seed(2)
finaldf2 = data.frame(Entry = sample.int(48), 
                     Row = rep(c(8:5), c(12,12,12,12)), 
                     Range = rep(c(1:12),4), 
                     Rep = rep(2,48))
finaldf3 = rbind(finaldf, finaldf2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rev`erse the unique elements in 'Row', create a named `vector`, match with the values of 'Row' after grouping by 'Rep'

```
finaldf_new <- df3 %>%
                 group_by(Rep) %>% 
                 mutate(Row = setNames(rev(unique(Row)),
                   unique(Row))[as.character(Row)]) %>%
                 ungroup
```

-testing with OP's expected

```
all.equal(finaldf3, finaldf_new, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```